# Open a application on the second Screen

Tags: x-server, openbox, window-management, chrome

I have one pc with one graphic card and two displays connected (one is a touchscreen).
Openbox is used a window manager.

I try to start two instances of the chromium-browser in the kiosk mode (--kiosk parameter).

The First instance should run on the normal screen and the second instance should run on the touch screen.

How i can move or start the second chromium-browser instance on the second screen ?

Comment: What exactly is your configuration?  "screen" and "display" have very specific meanings in X Windows, and the ways to get an application to appear on different monitors depends on how your system is set up.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367732/what-are-display-and-screen-with-regard-to-0-0

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you begin with these parameters (which assumes monitor one is 1024x768, monitor two is 800x600, and you want to go to ipchicken.com) in the script which launches the second instance of chromium-browser. Your mileage may vary; substitute parameter values as needed.

```
--chrome-frame --window-size=1024,768 --window-position=1025,001 --app="https://www.ipchicken.com"
```